# onClick loading new page before running my function

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

When a user clicks my link, I want a Javascript function to run which hides all the content on my page, and once that's complete, follow the link.  The following code I have works in Chrome, but not in Safari.

The problem is that Safari follows the link before it "hides" my page.  When I say "hide" my page, what I'm actually doing is setting the page's container div to "display:none";

(You may be asking why I'd like to hide my page on a link click - it's because I'm running this site on a tiny Arduino server and it takes several seconds before the new page loads.  So, my goal is to "hide" everything on the current page once you click the link to simulate quicker loading.)

Here is the code for the link:

```
<a href="add.htm" onclick="return clearScreen();"><span class="clickableDiv"></span>ADD DEVICE</a>
```

Note - the span allows the entire div, in which this link is located, to be clickable.

Here is the code for the function:

```
function clearScreen(){
  document.getElementById("container").style.display = 'none';
  return true;
}
```

If I set return to "false", it does effectively set container display to none.  Unfortunately, when set to false, it obviously doesn't follow my link.

I've also tried using window.location.href = "add.htm"; after my display = 'none';  -- but no luck.

And once again, this works perfectly in Chrome but not in Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="add.htm" onclick="clearScreen(this,event);"><span class="clickableDiv"></span>ADD DEVICE</a>

function clearScreen(link, event){
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("container").style.display = 'none';
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = link.href;
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: I gave it a try - but no luck.  It continued to follow the link before it hid my container.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Safari would stop doing updates to the page once you have started the navigation to the next page. You could try using a timeout so that the browser gets the control back long enough to do the update, then navigate to the new page.

Send the href along in the call:

```
<a href="add.htm" onclick="return clearScreen(this.href);">
```

In the function you return `false`, and set a timeout to do the navigation:

```
function clearScreen(href){
  document.getElementById("container").style.display = 'none';
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = href;
  }, 0);
  return false;
}
```